# Updating attribute value with Ajax success function doesn't get applied until manual page refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

When I try to rename my object "on click" via Ajax request and then try to update its element's attribute with this new name via Ajax success function, it doesn't fully work.

As I inspect the element in question with chrome, I can see that the attribute has indeed been updated after Ajax, but when I try to log this attribute "on click" again, it outputs the old value, and not the updated one. Only when I manually refresh the page, the updated value gets logged.

HTML rename icon:

This triggers a popover with input field when clicked on:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor"
    class="bi bi-pen-fill rename-add-icon rename-icon-sidebar" 
    data-bs-placement="top" data-sender="board" 
    data-action="rename" data-placeholder="" 
    data-value="{{ board.name }}" data-id="{{ board.id }}" 
    viewBox="0 0 16 16"> 
    <path d="m13.498.795.149-.149a1.207 1.207 0 1 1 1.707 1.708l-.149.148a1.5 1.5 0 0 1-.059 2.059L4.854 14.854a.5.5 0 0 1-.233.131l-4 1a.5.5 0 0 1-.606-.606l1-4a.5.5 0 0 1 .131-.232l9.642-9.642a.5.5 0 0 0-.642.056L6.854 4.854a.5.5 0 1 1-.708-.708L9.44.854A1.5 1.5 0 0 1 11.5.796a1.5 1.5 0 0 1 1.998-.001z" />
```

Javascript / jQuery:

```
function renameAddPopover() {
  $('.rename-add-icon').popover({
    html: true,
    sanitize: false,
    content: function () {
      return '<input class="card bg-dark text-light add-input" type="text" placeholder="' + $(this).data("placeholder") + '" value="' + $(this).data("value") + '" />'
    },
    // focus the input and put the prompt at the end of text
  }).on('shown.bs.popover', function () {

    var input = $('.add-input');
    var strLength = input.val().length;
    input.focus();
    input[0].setSelectionRange(strLength, strLength);

  });
}

function ajaxBoardManager(action, id, entered_name){
  // Post the data
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: 'http://localhost:8000/board_manager/',
    data: {
      name: entered_name,
      id: id,
      action: action,
      csrfmiddlewaretoken: getCookie('csrftoken'),
    },
    datatype: 'json',

    success: function (json) {

      if (action == 'rename'){
        // Update the name
        $('.board-item[value="'+id+'"]').html(json.name)

        // Update the rename-add-icon's data-value attribute, so when clicking on rename again
        // the input field gets pre-populated with this new name
        $('.rename-add-icon[data-id="'+id+'"]').attr('data-value', json.name)

        console.log($('.rename-add-icon[data-id="'+id+'"]').attr('data-value'))
      }
    },
    error: function (xhr, errmsg, err) {
    },
  });
}

$(document).ready(function () {
  // initialize the popover
  renameAddPopover();
  
  // RENAME OR ADD ICON
  $('.rename-add-icon').on('click', function () {
  
    sender = $(this).data('sender');
    action = $(this).data('action');
    id = $(this).data('id');
  
    value = $(this).data('value');
    placeholder = $(this).data('placeholder');
  
    console.log(value)
    
    renameAddPopover();
  
    // On pressing Enter
    $(".add-input").keypress(function (e) {
      if (e.which === 13) {
        // only if something is entered
        if ($('.add-input').val()) {
          e.preventDefault();
  
          entered_name = $(this).val();
  
          $('.rename-add-icon').popover('hide');
  
          if (sender == 'board') {
            ajaxBoardManager(action, id, entered_name)
          }
        }
      }
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: After first ajax on success refresh the function $('.rename-add-icon').on('click',...

Comment: Really bad practice adding event listeners inside other event handlers. If you click more than once you add a new event listener each time

Comment: Does this answer your question? [jQuery Data vs Attr?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7261619/jquery-data-vs-attr)

Comment: When you use `.data("name")` it stores it in memory, changing the html with `.prop("data-name", val)` does *not* change the stored value.   if you're using `.data()` then **always use** `.data()` - ie `.data("name", val)`

Comment: @charlietfl you mean all those "on" events? What would be the best way to restructure the code then?

Comment: No I mean the `keypress` inside `click`. Move it outside the click handler

Comment: I see, cuz the keypress is always listening, right? Still learning :)

Comment: If you click once... it sets up a key listener. Click twice it adds another one, third click 3 listeners etc

Comment: Hmm..weird. I moved keypress out of click, and now when I press Enter nothing happens.
EDIT:
Had to replace "$(.add-input').keypress(function (e)" with "$(document).keypress('.add-input', function (e)"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the issue is that when you update an `.attr` or a `.prop` it does **not** automatically update the value in `.data`

Try changing...

```
$('.rename-add-icon[data-id="'+id+'"]').attr('data-value', json.name)
```

To...

```
$('.rename-add-icon[data-id="'+id+'"]').data('value', json.name)
```